# Error Correction: Conversion Failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ALPHANUMERICVALUE' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

I am running into this error whenever I run my query.
[image]

I believe to fix this issue I have to Format the column which holds those values into a number by itself. I have already tried the Format() and Replace() functions, but they did not work for me. Any other suggestions?

```
SELECT
   e.accountingcode AS [Vehicle],
   Concat(e.year + ' ', e.make + ' ', e.model + ' ', Cast( e.[Description] AS VARCHAR(80))) AS NAME,
   Iif(cff.stringtype = '', cff1.stringtype, cff.stringtype) AS 'Operator',
   fta.fluid,
   so.odometer,
   CASE
      WHEN
         COALESCE(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer), 0) <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(so.odometer) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer) 
   END
   AS 'Previous Odometer', so.odometer - Iif(( 
   CASE
      WHEN
         COALESCE(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer), 0) <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(so.odometer) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer) 
   END
) = 0, so.odometer, 
   CASE
      WHEN
         COALESCE( Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer), 0) <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(so.odometer) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer) 
   END
) AS 'Miles Traveled', sh.hour, 
   CASE
      WHEN
         COALESCE(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour), 0) <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(sh.hour) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour) 
   END
   AS 'Previous Hours', sh.hour - Iif(( 
   CASE
      WHEN
         COALESCE(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour), 0) <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(sh.hour) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour) 
   END
) = 0, sh.hour, 
   CASE
      WHEN
         COALESCE(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour), 0) <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(sh.hour) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour) 
   END
) AS 'Hours Used' , fta.fifototalcost / fta.totalgallons AS [Avg Price], fta.totalgallons AS [Total Gallons], fta.fifototalcost AS [Total Cost]
```

The e.AccountingCode column contains the value that is at error.

Comment: I'll go ahead and share the rest of the select statement and apologize ahead of time because it is a formatting nightmare. @RandiVertongen

Comment: It looks like there may be some implicit conversion going on.  Since `AccountingCode` appears to allow non-numeric data, what happens if you change your `COALESCE` statement to use `'0'` instead of numeric 0 like so -  `'0') <> e.AccountingCode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem seems to be on the Coalesce's.**

> Returns the data type of expression with the highest data type
>   precedence. If all expressions are nonnullable, the result is typed as
>   nonnullable.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

For example:

```
select coalesce('101R',0)
```

Gives the error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '101R' to data type int.
```

This works fine:

```
select coalesce('101R','0')
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
101R
```

If the lag function on e.accountingcode can't be NULL, then you could use `ISNULL()`, but you should look into the differnces with coalesce.

> Returns the same type as check_expression. If a literal NULL is
>   provided as check_expression, returns the datatype of the
>   replacement_value. If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression
>   and no replacement_value is provided, returns an int.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Or in other words, if the first value is not a NULL value, return that datatype, if it is NULL and a replacement value, in our case 0 is passed,  then it will be that datatype. If all are NULL then it will be an integer.

**Solution #1, changing 0 to '0'**

```
SELECT
   e.accountingcode AS [Vehicle],
   Concat(e.year + ' ', e.make + ' ', e.model + ' ', Cast( e.[Description] AS VARCHAR(80))) AS NAME,
   Iif(cff.stringtype = '', cff1.stringtype, cff.stringtype) AS 'Operator',
   fta.fluid,
   so.odometer,
   CASE
      WHEN
         COALESCE(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer), '0') <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(so.odometer) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer) 
   END
   AS 'Previous Odometer', so.odometer - Iif(( 
   CASE
      WHEN
         COALESCE(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer), '0') <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(so.odometer) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer) 
   END
) = 0, so.odometer, 
   CASE
      WHEN
         COALESCE( Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer), '0') <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(so.odometer) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer) 
   END
) AS 'Miles Traveled', sh.hour, 
   CASE
      WHEN
         COALESCE(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour), '0') <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(sh.hour) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour) 
   END
   AS 'Previous Hours', sh.hour - Iif(( 
   CASE
      WHEN
         COALESCE(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour), '0') <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(sh.hour) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour) 
   END
) = 0, sh.hour, 
   CASE
      WHEN
         COALESCE(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour), '0') <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(sh.hour) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour) 
   END
) AS 'Hours Used' , fta.fifototalcost / fta.totalgallons AS [Avg Price], fta.totalgallons
```

**Solution #2, changing coalesce to ISNULL()**

Educate yourself on the differences with coalesce, for example only do this when the LAG() function on e.accountingcode can't return NULL, which kind of defeats the purpose of the isnull

```
SELECT
   e.accountingcode AS [Vehicle],
   Concat(e.year + ' ', e.make + ' ', e.model + ' ', Cast( e.[Description] AS VARCHAR(80))) AS NAME,
   Iif(cff.stringtype = '', cff1.stringtype, cff.stringtype) AS 'Operator',
   fta.fluid,
   so.odometer,
   CASE
      WHEN
         ISNULL(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer), 0) <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(so.odometer) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer) 
   END
   AS 'Previous Odometer', so.odometer - Iif(( 
   CASE
      WHEN
         ISNULL(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer), 0) <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(so.odometer) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer) 
   END
) = 0, so.odometer, 
   CASE
      WHEN
         ISNULL( Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer), 0) <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(so.odometer) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, so.odometer) 
   END
) AS 'Miles Traveled', sh.hour, 
   CASE
      WHEN
         ISNULL(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour), 0) <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(sh.hour) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour) 
   END
   AS 'Previous Hours', sh.hour - Iif(( 
   CASE
      WHEN
         ISNULL(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour), 0) <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(sh.hour) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour) 
   END
) = 0, sh.hour, 
   CASE
      WHEN
         ISNULL(Lag(e.accountingcode) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour), 0) <> e.accountingcode 
THEN
   0 
ELSE
   Lag(sh.hour) OVER ( partition BY e.accountingcode 
ORDER BY
   e.accountingcode, sh.hour) 
   END
) AS 'Hours Used' , fta.fifototalcost / fta.totalgallons AS [Avg Price], fta.totalgallons
```

Comment: Awesome! I had a feeling that the COALESCE function may have had something to do with it. I will definitely be educating myself on the differences!

Comment: Great! Glad it helped, good luck :)